# How to use knockout.js data binding when ajax request periodically auto refreshes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

In my application I periodically makes ajax call once every 5 seconds to get new update from server.

My ajax data from server is JSON array that looks like:
[
  {
    "foo": "valx",
    "bar": "valy"

},
  {
    "foo": "valw",
    "bar": "valz"
  }
]

My ajax code is:

```
(function update() {

    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : url,
        data : {

        },
        dataType : "json",
        global : false,
        success : function(content, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        myViewModel = content;
        ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);

        },
        complete: function() {

         setTimeout(update, 5000);
          },

        error: function( xhr, textStatus ) {

            }
    });
    })();
```

My HTML is:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: myViewModel">
                        <tr>
                            <td data-bind="text: foo"></td>
                            <td data-bind="text: bar"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

But this does not work and I get error after first ajax call:
You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You're close.  You only call `applyBindings` once.  Instead what you should be doing is setting an `observable` property on your view model.

Here is how you would setup your view model:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.data = ko.observableArray();
};

var viewModel = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Then when you have new data (e.g. in your `ajax` call):

```
$.ajax({
    success : function(content, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        viewModel.data(content);
    }
});
```

Note: You could set the data a few different ways.  If you want your timed event outside the view model then you can use the view model instance (in my example, `viewModel`) to access the properties and update them.  You could place the timed event within your view model if you want and then just call `self.data(content)` (or something similar).